# sqlite query python

Tags: sql, sqlite

i want to perform the below query

```
SELECT t1.patient_report, COUNT(*) AS cnt, t1.doctor_report, (SELECT t2.doctor_report FROM infoTable t2 WHERE t2.patient_report = t1.patient_report AND cnt > 1 LIMIT 3) AS Doctors FROM infoTable t1 WHERE t1.patient_report != 'N/A' GROUP BY t1.patient_report ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

but i got this error!

```
Result: no such column: cnt
```

please how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: Few things:

 1. The `AS` clause is missing in the outer query. It should be `COUNT(*) as cnt`
 2. The inner query does not have the reference to `cnt`. You should use a `group by` function for the subquery and evaluate the count again.

Could you share a few records and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery can't access the aliased column `cnt` of the outer query.
But even if it did have accesss, another error would be thrown because the subquery may return more than 1 rows.
I think that you can do what you want with window functions and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT t.patient_report, t.cnt,
       GROUP_CONCAT(doctor_report) AS Doctors
FROM (
  SELECT patient_report, 
         doctor_report,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_report) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_report) cnt
  FROM infoTable 
  WHERE patient_report <> 'N/A' 
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 3 AND t.cnt > 1
GROUP BY t.patient_report, t.cnt
ORDER BY t.cnt DESC
```